# jQuery document ready after ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm having problems with updating elements that are not ready after an ajax request.

If I run my `myFunction()` function on page load like so:

```
$(function() {
 myFunction();
}
```

I have no problems at all. But if I then use something like

```
$.ajax({
      url: this.href,
      dataType: "script",
      complete: function(xhr, status) {
        myFunction();
      }
    });
```

which returns `$(".myElement").replaceWith("htmlHere")`. The elements are simply not ready when the complete event fires. If I set a delay in there it works fine again.

Is there any other event that gets fired other than 'complete' when the DOM is ready?

Update:

Here's the actual code:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.remote").live("click", function(e) {    
    $.ajax({
      url: this.href,
      dataType: "script",
      success: function(xhr, status) {
                myFunction();
            }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });

  myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
    // Modify the dom in here
}
```

The missing ); was just a typo on my part.

Ive tried using success now instead of complete and it doesn't appear to make any difference.

Comment: what you do on success event of $.ajax? Is there some function that you should maybe mention in your question?

Comment: You want to place *all* your code inside one big `$(function () { ... });` handler. That way you never have that kind of issues... Btw doing this also gives you a namespace, which you need anyway.

Comment: Ive updated the original question with updated code.

Answer (score 5):

I have set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztpf4/2/) based on your code, and it seems to be working.

This is the current code:

```
 $(function() {
  $("a.remote").live("click", function(e) {    
    $.ajax({
      url: this.href,
      dataType: "script",
      success: function(xhr, status) {
                myFunction();
            }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });

});

function myFunction() {
    $("span").replaceWith("<p>test</p>");
}
```

And it replaces span tag with a paragraph. Please check it and compare with your code. If it is the same, then your problem somewhere other than this function (maybe in myFunction?).

Comment: +1 for doing work to reproduce the problem, which is thankless when there is no reply.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` to wrap up anything you want fired when the DOM has loaded. Your ajax request could be placed inside the `document.ready` if you want this to wait until the dom has loaded.

If you want to wait until the ajax has loaded its resource then you should use `ajax.success` rather than `complete`.

Answer (score 3):

Just change `complete:` to `success:` in your `$.ajax()` call:

```
$.ajax({
      url: this.href,
      dataType: "script",
      success: function(xhr, status) {
        //make your DOM changes here
        myFunction();
      }
});
```

The `success` function will run once the AJAX request receives a successful response. So make your DOM changes within that function, and then run `myFunction()`.

**Edit**
You seem to be trying to make the DOM changes using your `myFunction()`. But if you don't first insert the HTML received in the AJAX response into the DOM, then there will be nothing for `myFunction()` to modify. If this is indeed what's happening, then you have two options:

1. Insert the response HTML into the DOM, then call `myFunction()` (and all of this should happen within the `success` callback function).
2. Pass the AJAX response to `myFunction()` as an argument, so that `myFunction()` can handle the DOM insertion and then do the necessary modification.

Comment: Please see the edit to my response. Let me know if that helps. If not, please clarify where exactly you insert the HTML from the AJAX response into the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

There is a event that triggers after every ajax call. It is called [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/).

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
});
```

So you can

```
function Init(){
  // stuff here
}

$(document).ready(function()
  Init();
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function()
  Init();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing parenthesis of the document ready wrapper function.

```
$(function() {
 myFunction();
});
```

Note the `});` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
 myFunction();
}
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 myFunction();
});
```

Or incase you want the ajax to run on load. Do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax();
});
```

Comment: `$(function() { ... })` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready`. It's only missing a  `)`.

Comment: Even so, the above code seems like he was putting the ajax outside of dom ready event.